# contentful rich text not rendering

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm trying to log out the raw and so far I can't get anything in the console. It just shows up as an empty array. There must be something wrong with my Query as all i can find on the docs is how to render ContentfulAsset but not actual text which i can format with CSS

```js
/* eslint-disable */
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';

export const query = graphql`
    query MyQuery($slug: String) {
        contentfulLongPost(Slug: { eq: $slug }) {
            title
            updatedAt(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
            body {
                raw
                references {
                    ... on ContentfulAsset {
                        contentful_id
                        __typename
                    }
                }
            }
            free
            contentType
        }
    }
`;

const caseStudy = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    

    return (
        <Layout>
        
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default caseStudy;
```

What do I put after __typename to get the raw?

query MyQuery($slug: String) {
contentfulLongPost(Slug: {eq: $slug}) {
title
updatedAt(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
body {
raw
}
}
}

`;

Comment: `__typename` is inside `ContentfulAsset` but you said you are getting trouble rendering rich text, which is a `raw` field. Can you clarify it? In addition, can you show how you are getting the data in the component?

Comment: hi sorry i mean the raw. Basically, can you show me how I would render my body raw which is rich text on the screen?

Comment: If you are not even fetching it (empty array) you won't be able to display it, so maybe there's an issue with your query. That's why I'm asking you to provide how you print that data in the component/page, to debug a little bit more

Comment: ive edited the question, im just logging out props to see whats there. I  think using ContentfulAsset is wrong but im not sure what else to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong there... `caseStudy` must be `CaseStudy` since it's a React component, otherwise, it will be interpreted as an HTML element which obviously will break your code (`<caseStudy>` doesn't exist... yet).

Even if `ContentfulAsset` fragment is wrong, if your query is correct, you should get something inside the `raw` field (located at `props.data.contentfulLongPost.raw`) so check it again. If you are just trying to print the rich text, while your query doesn't break, you can print what's inside `raw` without data in the `ContentfulAsset` fragment.

Maybe what it's wrong if the filter that is hold by the `$slug` variable, so even if the query is correct, you are not able to fetch the data because there's not any data to fetch.

Once you ensure that your data is being fetched properly (you have data inside `props.data`) you can customize the output by lifting your data to:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

Source: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/

A full customizable example can be checked (almost copy/pasted) at: https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer

The idea is to create a custom object that will parse your fetched data with a custom HTML/React component:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"

const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>

const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}

function BlogPostTemplate({ data }) {

  return <div>{data.contentfulBlogPost && renderRichText(data.contentfulBlogPost, options)}</div>
}
```

Where `BlogPostTemplate` stands for your `CaseStudy` and `contentfulBlogPost` for your `contentfulLongPost`.

Summarizing:

- Fix your component naming
- Check what's inside `props.data.contentfulLongPost.raw`
- Check that you have any data with the provided `slug`. You can force the value of the slug in `localhost:8000/___graphql` to check what data is fetching your query.
- Customize the output using the `options` object and the `renderRichText` helper

Comment: Hi, so i am gettgin data when I log out props.data.contentfulLongPost.body.raw but in an object, and i still dont know what to put in the query?

Comment: If you are getting `raw`, **your query is fine**. To display it, follow the answer and the provided docs

Comment: but the docs say i need to use reference? at which point do i use that, ive edited my question to refelct how my query looks now. I feel like im getting closer now ..

Comment: Your question is literally: "contentful rich text not rendering" The docs base the code in a specific data structure. If you don't have references, simply don't use them. Don't expect a copy/paste. In the documentation `references` stands for `ContentfulAsset` what stands for all assets added rather than the pure ones in the Contentful dashboard (images, etc). You must adapt your query depending on your fields and names, all easily accessed at `localhost:8000/___graphql`, just clicking the fields you'll see what's inside and you'll be able to create a query, just need to copy/paste it

Comment: so the query i have now should work? providing I display it correctly?

Comment: It will rely on your data structure, I can not know that without seeing your project details, your Contentful dashboard, etc. Test it and try it.

Comment: Man @ShuibAbdillahi I think you are expecting a pure copy/paste answer. You've put the same question without even trying to resolve this one  (you don't have `bodyRichText ` so don't use it!), send directly your raw data `return <div>renderRichText(data.contentfulBlogPost, options)}</div>`

Comment: sorry, its just frustating because the query seems fine as im gettign raw data in my console, but now the screen is just blank

Comment: It's more frustrating on my side, believe me, xD. Try to provide more details about "just blank screen". Is there any error in the console? What's the code you've tried? Have you tried `return <div>renderRichText(data.contentfulBlogPost, options)}</div>`? Do you understand what you need to do?